# hive sql:having count multiple conditions

Tags: sql, hive

How to achieve multiple conditions in having count clause? Such as `case when prob=1 then having count(cust_id)<=3 or case when prob=0 then having count(cust_id)<=2`

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some data example with desired output

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a case when  seems you need  an or condition

```
 select  .. 
 from  ..  
 where ...
 group by prod...
 having prod=1 and count(cust_id)<=3
 OR prod=0 and count(cust_id)<=2
```

Comment: This seems right, but you need to be sure that `prod` is in the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  ...correct thanks  ... answer  updated  with your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the next solution, in case prod is just a column in the table and by "count(cust_id)" you want to count the number of occurrences per cust_id in the table:

```
select   cust_id
         , count(*)

from     <table_name>
where    prod=1
having   count(*) <= 3  

union

select   cust_id
         , count(*)

from     <table_name>
where    prod=0
having   count(*) <= 2
```